# Detect if I get close to a mark in android maps

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm trying to make a app with the google maps API, I created the activity with google maps and set my actual location. I created one mark and i want to alert me if i get close in a determinate distance of this mark.

I searched for the geofence API but I don't understand how this API work and how to implement this code to my use.

My MainActivity class:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng latlon = new LatLng(-22.9274767,-47.0775973);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlon).title("Title").snippet("subtitle"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlon));

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
    if (mMap != null) {


        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()), 18);
                mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("It's Me!"));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Play with this stuff [Get Notified When Location Changes](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/get-notified-when-location-changes). Hope you will find what you want.

Comment: It should be easy to (given the coordinates of both points) calc the distance between them in Km. Whats the problem with that?

Comment: I dont see any of the geofencing api in your code, did you try the examples shown here: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html ?

Comment: the examples are here in case you missed the link in the article: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing

Answer (score 0):

You can use your [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and [LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) in order to get your current location. Then you should calculate the distance between the marker and your location.

To calculate the distance approximately you may use the following code:

```
final static double earthRadius = 6371000; // the average earth radius
public static double distance (double Lat1,double Lng1,double Lat2,double Lng2)
{
    double latRadius = earthRadius*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(Lat1));

    double dLat = Math.abs(Lat1-Lat2),
            dLon=Math.abs(Lng1-Lng2);

    if(dLat>180) dLat-=360;
    if(dLon>180) dLon-=360;

    double dy = earthRadius *Math.toRadians(dLat),
            dx = latRadius *Math.toRadians(dLon);

    double d= Math.sqrt(dy*dy+dx*dx);

    return d;
}
```